# Python using multiprocessing Processes stops on its way

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I would like to use a few processes/threads of my computer to accelerate Python's work.
Using multiprocessing seemed to be more appropriate and recommended.

I have many independant files to be read and interpreted inside a *for* loop and I wish to start 1 Process (from multiprocessing's class Process) per file to read and make associated calculations.
As I might have thousands of files and to treat 1 requires 60s, it can take ages to Python to calculate.

The code launches well, works well, IF not too many files are asked.
**For large amount of files **(for example 100 000), **Python appears to stop.**

The point it stops seems to depend on the computer... but it will stop at some point fore sure.
**I use Python 3+ .**

First, a list of all the thousands processes was made and all Processes were started at the same time.
As it stoped I thought it be fair my humble computer struggles starting thousands of processes at the same time. I then started to launch only groups of *NProcs *Processes, but Python still stops...

I read using a Queue() would be better than a Manager(), but it can be changed.

Here is my code in a simple version. **Python stops at the join step **after many iterations...

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Queue, Pool
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import os
#import psutil



# Simple function (as an example)
def add_to_queue(Q, element):
    time.sleep(0)
    Q.put(element)


def main(NProcs, OPTION):
    FILES_TO_READ = [i for i in range(100000)]
    start = time.time()
    Q = Queue()
    if __name__ == "__main__":  # Needed here....?

        if NProcs >1 :

                # Initialization of the total amount of groups
                #  (each group will have to use max Nprocs processes)
                Ngroups = len(FILES_TO_READ)//NProcs
                if len(FILES_TO_READ)//NProcs != len(FILES_TO_READ)/NProcs:
                     Ngroups = Ngroups +1
                    
                    
                

                ## Define all the possible processes to launch
                # processes = []
                # for i in range(len(FILES_TO_READ)):
                #     p = Process(target=add_to_queue, args=(Q,i))
                #     processes.append(p)
                    
                
                
                for group_i in range(Ngroups):
                    print('\nGroup number ',group_i,'with max',NProcs,'processes')
                    start_i =     NProcs * group_i
                    end_i   = min(NProcs * (group_i+1) , len(FILES_TO_READ))
                    
                    on_going_processes = []
                    for i in range(start_i, end_i):
                        p =  Process(target=add_to_queue, args=(Q,i))
                        on_going_processes.append(p)
                    
                    # Start NProcs processes
                    print('\tstart')
                    for p in on_going_processes :                        
                        p.start()
                        
                    # Join them
                    print('\tjoin')
                    for p in on_going_processes:
                        p.join()
                        if p.is_alive() :
                            print('\nWARNING : Still alive')
                    
                    # Close them
                    print('\tclose')
                    for p in on_going_processes :
                        p.close()


        #########################################################
        # Classic version of launching Python (no multiprocessing)
        else :
            for i in range(len(FILES_TO_READ)): 
                add_to_queue(Q, i)

            
            
            
    end         = time.time()
    delta_time  = round(end-start,2)
        
    # Make some lambda operations on the Q used by the different processes...
    # Empty Q and make a list out of its elements
    Q_LISTED = []
    while not Q.empty():
        element = Q.get()
        Q_LISTED.append(element)
    print('____________')
    print('Results')
    for element in Q_LISTED :
        print('\t',element)
    
    
    
    
    print('\ntook',delta_time,'s')
    print('\n___________________________')
    print('  ...\n      THE END\n              ...')
    
    
    
    return 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(10,'PROCESS')
```

Comment: The typical number of Processes launched by one program is more or less equal to the number of independent cores on your computer's processor.  Nowhere near 100,000.  If each calculation takes 60 seconds, you're talking the equivalent of about 70 days of computing power.  The best you can achieve by parallelization is to divide that time by the number of cores.  Then, what are going to do with all that data?  You probably can't keep it all in the computer's memory.  I think you, my friend, are fighting a losing battle here.  Perhaps it's time to rethink your approach?

Answer (score 0):

Despite using groups, you still created almost 100,000 processes, create new process is a heavy operation, moreover, these processes heavily utilize system resources, e.g. CPU and memory.

For your use case, it is recommend to utilize a process pool, where a fixed amount of processes can efficiently handle all the files (could use [multiprocessing.pool.Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) or concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor)

```
def add_to_queue_v2(element):  # remove the Q param
    time.sleep(0)
    return element  # return instead of put to Queue

pool = Pool()
result = pool.map(add_to_queue_v2, FILES_TO_READ)
```